# Roscore on virtual machine

Tags: ros, roscore, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to run roscore on virtual machine in cloud and connect robots to it.
I have installed ros on vm. I have a openvpn server running as well, so robots could communicate with cloud and vice versa.
On my robot I have openvpn client running.

Lets say my IP on vm is: 1.1.1.1 and virtual network ip is 2.2.2.2

On robot ip: 3.3.3.3 and virtual network ip 4.4.4.4

On vm: openvpn server running, roscore running, I used
export ROS_HOSTNAME=2.2.2.2

On robot: openvpn client running,
I used export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://mycloud.cloudapp.net:11311 and export ROS_HOSTNAME=4.4.4.4

And I get the error "Unable to communicate with master" on my robot.

Can anyone help me with this issue.Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227934/roscore-on-virtual-machine/) by [mielto](https://answers.ros.org/users/26127/mielto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your ROS_MASTER_URI is using a domain name, which might be linked to the public IP.
You might want to try ROS_MASTER_URI=http://4.4.4.4:11311
The VM and your robot should use the same IP and ports. Otherwise you are not trying to connect to the same rosmaster.

You want to run your master in the cloud so all IPs should be 4.4.4.4
you should have then on your VM ROS_HOSTNAME=4.4.4.4

---

Originally posted by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) with karma: 381 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0